# Error messages in Multilingual part of the site

Tags: plugins

The english part of our viking-realestate.com site is working perfectly, but we are suddenly getting the following error messages on the german part: What could be the issue?

Warnung: sprintf (): Zu wenige Argumente in /home/ewjsbqew/public_html/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/config/containers/shortcode-vc-row.php online 184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your plugin compatibility with your theme. I think it's happening for an update. Plugin may be outdated.